# Editing zip file in memory and returning it via http response results in a corrupt file

Tags: go

Hey guys am new to go exactly 23 hours and 10 minutes new so obviously am having issues with some stuff, I have a zip file that is in memory and I would like to take that file make a copy of it add some files to the copy and return the file via HTTP, it works but when I open the file it seems to be corrupted

```
outFile, err := os.OpenFile("./template.zip", os.O_RDWR, 0666)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to open zip for writing: %s", err)
}
defer outFile.Close()


zipw := zip.NewWriter(outFile)

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(zipw))
for _, appCode := range appPageCodeText {
    f, err := zipw.Create(appCode.Name + ".jsx")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err = f.Write([]byte(appCode.Content)) //casting it to byte array and writing to file
}

// Clean up
err = zipw.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer outFile.Close()

//Get the Content-Type of the file
//Create a buffer to store the header of the file in
FileHeader := make([]byte, 512)
//Copy the headers into the FileHeader buffer
outFile.Read(FileHeader)
//Get content type of file
 fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(outFile))
//Get the file size
FileStat, _ := outFile.Stat()                      //Get info from file
FileSize := strconv.FormatInt(FileStat.Size(), 10) //Get file size as a string

buffer := make([]byte, FileStat.Size())

outFile.Read(buffer)


//Send the headers
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+"template.zip")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", FileSize)
outFile.Seek(0, 0)
// io.Copy(w, buffer) //'Copy' the file to the client
w.Write(buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. (The primary problem): you `Read` the first 512 bytes of `outFile` into `FileHeader`, which means that they're *not* read into `buffer`, which means the first 512 bytes of the file aren't sent to the client. You do a `Seek`, but too late for it to be useful — the contents of `buffer` are already set at that point. You need to move the Seek earlier, or write both buffers, or just remove the unnecessary `FileHeader` read.
2. Your comment claims that you do so to get the content-type of the file, but `FileHeader` is actually never used. And why would it be? You *know* what the type of the file is, you just wrote it. So the separate read of the first 512 bytes is unneeded.
3. Actually, it's all unneeded — Instead of making a file on disk, using a `zip.Writer` to write to the file, re-opening the file from disk, reading it into a byte array, and then writing that byte array to the HTTP client, you could simply either have the `zip.Writer` write directly to the HTTP client (if you don't care about setting `Content-Length`), or have it write to a `bytes.Buffer` and then copy that buffer out to the HTTP client (if an accurate `Content-Length` is important to you).

The first version looks like:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=template.zip")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
zipw := zip.NewWriter(w)
// Your for loop to add items to the zip goes here.
//
zipw.Close() // plus error handling
```

And the second version looks like:

```
buffer := &bytes.Buffer{}
zipw := zip.NewWriter(buffer)
// Your for loop to add items to the zip goes here.
//
zipw.Close() // plus error handling
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=template.zip")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(buffer.Length(), 10))
io.Copy(w, buffer) // plus error handling
```

Comment: could u show me the code to copy the file into the buffer?

Comment: implemented the solution didn't prove to be any different but thanks